# Upgrading Angular using Yeoman

Tags: yeoman

I just installed Angular as follow:

```
npm install -g generator-angular  # install generator
yo angular                        # scaffold out a AngularJS project
bower install angular-ui          # install a dependency for your project from Bower
grunt test                        # test your app
grunt server                      # preview your app
grunt                             # build the application for deployment
```

That installed 1.0.7 instead of 1.0.8.

I am totally new to Yeoman. How can I upgrade 1.0.7 to 1.0.8? Is this supposed to be done manually?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**Bower** that comes with Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/packagemanager.html) to update the dependencies. In Bower, dependencies are listed in a ‘bower.json’ file, similar to Node’s package.json or the Ruby Gemfile.

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
      "angular": "~1.0.8"
  }
}
```

First list the installed packages:

```
bower list
```

And to update a package you use the following command:

```
bower update angular
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a bower install angular-ui you will get version 0.40 ... this is not compatible with Bootstrap 3 (if that's what you want.  If you want the latest angular-ui you'll have to manually install it.